# Javascript Variables not adding together

Tags: javascript

Simple javascript and probably simple solution I am missing.

```js
var x = 0;
var y = 0;
var z = 0;

z = x + y;

y += 5;

console.log('x', x)
console.log('y', y)
console.log('z', z)
```

console shows  y = 5;
but console shows z = 0;

Shouldn't z now be equal to 5?

Comment: Why would you expect that? You already computed the value of `z` before you change `y`

Comment: z gets the value of x + y at the moment of assignment. Subsequent changes to y will not affect the value of z. That is how it is supposed to work.

Comment: it is zero because `0 + 0 = 0` you need to increment `y` before you add to `z`

Comment: it's all about order of execution

Comment: `z` is assigned _by value_ (not reference) because Number is a primitive in JavaScript

Comment: It sounds like you're expecting the variables to be evaluated at time-of-use, but this is *not* the case. For example, once you do `z = x + y`, it sets `z` to `0` and has *no* concern for how that was determined. It does not remember that `x` or `y` have any relevance to that value whatsoever. Perhaps your confusion relates to *"reference vs value"* as it pertains to programming.

Comment: I want z to always be updated based on the values of x and y.   An expanded example would be,  var item1 = 0;   var item2 = 0;   var total = 0;  total = item1 + item2;     item1 += 5;     why would this not make total increase by 5?      what would I need to do to make sure total is always being updated?

Comment: Would I need to just make a function     (){ z = x + y} ;   and call that function everytime a change is made to x or y?

Comment: @Soonerdev You could make `z` a function by doing `var z = () => x + y;`. Doing `z()` would then give you *the current sum of `x` + `y`*.

Comment: @TylerRoper   I think comments cleared up my confusion.   Thank you.   I was  trying to give you stackoverflow kudos, but can't find a way to do that from the comment section.

Comment: No worries. You've received a handful of answers, you can kindly select whichever you believe to be most helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do `var z = x + y`, you're setting `z` to the *current* sum of `x` and `y`. From that point on, `z` is simply `0`. It has no reference to `x` or `y` anymore.

If you want the value of `z` to be continuously calculated *at time-of-use*, then perhaps you'd prefer a function:

```js
var x = 0;
var y = 0;
var z = () => x+y;  //function z() { return x+y; }

console.log( z() );

x = 5;
y = 3;

console.log( z() );
```

Comment: Thanks again for the help.   I have a much more detailed script with an online board game I am trying to code and had made a solution by incrementing "z"  by as much any time x or y were incremented.   I just didn't understand why I had to keep updating "z" and including it in all of my other functions.    Thanks again.

Comment: @Soonerdev Not a problem. Once you feel comfortable, you could also make use of [*getters*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get). They return a property value that gets determined *at time of lookup*, just like the code above.

Answer (score 2):

You need to update `y` and then `z`, assuming you want `z` to equal 5:

```js
// x, y, and z are 0
var x = 0;
var y = 0;
var z = 0;

// y is 5
// this is equivalent to y = 5, because y starts at 0 anyway
y += 5;

// z = 0 (x) + 5 (y)
z = x + y;
```

Or, you can evaluate `z`'s calculation at runtime using a function, like so:

```js
// x, y, and z are 0
var x = 0;
var y = 0;
var z = 0;    
function getZ() {
    return x + y
}

// z = 0 (x) + 0 (y) = 0
console.log(getZ());

// y is 5
// this is equivalent to y = 5, because y starts at 0 anyway
y += 5;

// z = 0 (x) + 5 (y) = 5
console.log(getZ());
```

You can learn more about the [`Function`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions) and [`Number`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number) types on the [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/).

Comment: This solves the issue of getting the updated total.  Thanks for all who commented.   I think TyleRoper   had the answer as to why my confusion was there to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

Because `z` will get the current value `x` and `y`and Javascript will execute your code from the top to the bottom in order. [Read more here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imperative_programming).

```js
var x = 0;
var y = 0;
var z = 0;

function addXAndY(){
  return x + y;
}
z = addXAndY();

y += 5;

console.log('x', x)
console.log('y', y)
console.log('z', z)

z = addXAndY();
console.log('new z', z) //this will return 5 since you added a new value to y
```

Answer (score 0):

In your current approach:

```
var x = 0;
var y = 0;
var z = 0;
z = x + y;
```

when variable `z` is evaluated, it uses the current values stored on variables `x` and `y`. At that point those values are `0` for both `x` and `y`, so `z` will store a `0` (result of `0 + 0`). Future changes on variable `x` and `y` won't change the value stored at `z`. However, if you want to keep an updated value of the sum of both variables `x` and `y` you can defined `z` as a function. Then you can call the function to get the updated value at any time. Example:

```js
var x = 0;
var y = 0;
var z = () => x + y;
y += 5;
console.log("x: " + x, "y: " + y, "z: " + z());
x += 3;
console.log("x: " + x, "y: " + y, "z: " + z());
x += 22;
console.log("x: " + x, "y: " + y, "z: " + z());
```

Answer (score 0):

just a quick example how this would work with a getter:

Tyler Roper already mentioned them.

```js
var obj = {
  x: 0,
  y: 0,
  get z() {
    return this.x + this.y
  }
};

console.log(obj);

obj.y += 5;

console.log("obj.y += 5");
console.log(obj);

obj.x = 3;

console.log("obj.x = 3");
console.log(obj);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{top:0;max-height:100%!important}
```

Here I used the getter with a simple object (literal), but you can also define them on some class (prototype), so that it is shared among all instances.